# assign a template to multiple titles in XML/XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a template and would like to apply the "role" pageTitle it to all my titles.

this is my template:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@role = 'subtitle'">
            <fo:block font-size="14pt" line-height="14pt"
                color="#502a7d" font-family="AvenirNextLTProBold"
                padding-top="0.2cm">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@role = 'contractTitle'">
            <fo:block font-size="13pt" line-height="13pt"
                color="#00a6ce" font-family="AvenirNextLTProBold"
                padding-top="0.5cm">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@role = 'blackTitleWithPara'">
            <fo:block font-size="14pt"
                font-family="AvenirNextLTW01-Demi" padding-top="0.5cm">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@role = 'pageTitle'">
            
            <fo:block font-size="30pt" line-height="30pt"
                color="#502a7d" font-family="AvenirNextLTProBold">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            </fo:block>
            
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

my fo:blocks look like this:

```
                    <fo:block id="part-C">
                        <xsl:call-template name="I18N"><xsl:with-param name="termId" select="&quot;partC.title&quot;"/></xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
                    </fo:block>

                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:call-template name="I18N"><xsl:with-param name="termId" select="&quot;partC.title2&quot;"/></xsl:call-template>
                    </fo:block>
```

And this is how I try to apply it to my titles which is wrong.

```
<title role="pageTitle">
        <term id="partC.title">
                <translation language="en">Part C</translation>
                <translation language="fr">Partie C</translation>
            </term>
            
        <term id="partC.title2">
                <translation language="en">Part C</translation>
                <translation language="fr">Partie C</translation>
            </term>
    </title>
```

I noticed if I put the role="pageTitle" in each translation tag it works. but I would like to apply it to all my titles without copying it everytime.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In other words, how can I apply the same template to these 2 elements in my xml file:

```
<term id="partC.title">
                <translation language="en">Part C</translation>
                <translation language="fr">Partie C</translation>
            </term>
<term id="partB.title">
                <translation language="en">Part B</translation>
                <translation language="fr">Partie B</translation>
            </term>
```

considering this would be my template in the xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <fo:block font-size="30pt" line-height="30pt"
                color="#502a7d" font-family="AvenirNextLTProBold">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example input, an executable XSLT and the expected result.

Comment: It's rather difficult to see what you are doing wrong without seeing a complete source XML and a complete XSLT stylesheet. You've just shown us fragments and it's hard to see how they fit together. You also haven't shown us what output you are trying to produce.

Comment: Your code does `<xsl:value-of select="text()" />` in the case where `title/@role = 'pageTitle'`, but in your fragment of XML containing a title element with @role = 'pageTitle', the `title` element has no child text nodes other than whitespace.